# How to scrape a website's href (changing with session) from the inspect element, and not the source code of the page

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

Requirement: [Trying to fetch the href from inspect element and store in a variable, then perform python requests.get() to fetch the data]
To get the COVID R0 data from the site : https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/ into `S3` , create a data pipeline and create a dashboard.

Steps to reproduce :

1. Navigate to https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/ -> Custom Datasets
2. Select Current
3. Select R-Effective
4. By County -> Select All county from dropdown
5. Right click on the Download Custom Dataset option :Copy link address
6. Use this address to get the data [The link changes after every few minutes, and gets the latest session added to the URL]

Approach:
I am able to get the dataset into S3, but since the link changes and contains a session, the script is unable to fetch the data.
When I do a view source code option, I do not see the href there, but "Inspect element" does show the latest href.
I am new to selenium, but whatever I could explore shows that it should be doable using selenium with python.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capa)
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.set_window_size(1440,900)
driver.get('https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/')
time.sleep(10)
xpath = "//*[contains(@href, ‘dl.canned?’)]"myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , xpath)))
```

Sample link :
https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/_w_3192292b/session/31bb334f1496250a1e17875f129054d7/download/dl.custom?w=3192292b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the `head` mode instead of the `headless`. For example this gets you `Statewide R-Effective over Time` canned dataset.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-value="Downloads"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dl.canned"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Then, check your default downloads folder.

EDIT:

To get the custom data set, I fooled around with `selenium` and came up with this. Hacky, but works. :-]

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-value="Downloads"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-id="cust.dl.bygeo"]')

(
    ActionChains(driver)
    .click(button)
    .send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    .send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    .send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
    .perform()
)

time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dl.custom"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks alot @baduker for looking into it. I am able to get the custom dataset using the head mode as you suggested.'//*[@id="dl.custom"]').click() However, I would like to get the R-effective datasets for all the county. On the webpage, Custom Datasets -> R-effective -> By County -> Under dropdown choose select All ; once all the county gets selected , we need to download the data. Sorry, my questions might be basic as I am using selenium for the first time. So, basically how do we choose the values from the dropdown, and get the data.

Comment: Thanks @baduker, we are almost there to what we need. I made the changes suggested by you, and we are getting the custom dataset for "by Region" and "California". However, we need to get the data "by County" and in the dropdown below we need to choose "Select All" so, that basically selects all counties and then we need to "Download Custom Dataset". Could you please let me know what additional changes we need to make. Thanks !

Comment: That's the same data set... You *already* have what you're after. Have you even checked the file? Go download those custom sets by selecting all counties and then by region and all counties. Also, both methods give you the same description: `The requested file is 3.6 Mb and has 6 columns and 79148 rows`.

Comment: Really appreciate your time and effort in helping me on this issue, was stuck on it since few days. Thank you.

Comment: This works completely fine on my local system, however we need to move the data to AWS. Is there a way we can get the href from "Inspect element" : <a id="dl.custom" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" href="session/5a7d29de6d3e50bf9b82e100b7249ad7/download/dl.custom?w=97792af4" target="_blank" download>...</a> == $0 . We can store href value in a variable and create the URL : https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/_w_97792af4/session/5a7d29de6d3e50bf9b82e100b7249ad7/download/dl.custom?w=97792af4 ; which can then be used to make a REST call and get the data.